# Text to table with v lookup

Tags: text, table

I have file as below

FileName:File1.txt
[image: Text File]
Can we get the format as below table

[image: Table Format Required]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '
!($3 in T1)     {SQ[++CNT] = $3
                }
                {T1[$3] = T1[$3] DL[$3] $1
                 T2[$3] = T2[$3] DL[$3] $2
                 DL[$3] = ","
                }
END             {for (i=1; i<=CNT; i++) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t", T1[SQ[i]], T2[SQ[i]], SQ[i]
                print _
                }
' file
1,3 2,4 5s  5   6   16s 7   8   23s
```

Comment: i was able to use the tr command to remove the line breaks and make the spaces into tabs to be put into a table format.  tr -s "\t" " " <sed9.txt >sed10.txt
tr "\n" "\t" < sed10.txt >sed11.txt
 but kind of lost how to match the name (ex. 5s and to structure it into the required format)

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative sledgehammer with GNU `awk` using newline or space as field separator `-F'[\n ]'` which also requires `RS=""` in order to avoid any `\n` being taken as a record separator.

```
awk -F'[\n ]' 'BEGIN{RS=""; OFS="\t"}
    {print  substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4), $1","$4, $2","$5, $3, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12}
    ' *.txt
```

Output:

```
 File1   1,3     2,4     5s      5       6       16s     7       8       23s
```